# Play video one after another in a row using javascript And PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list of videos name that i want to run 
but not know how to run video one after the other automatically

```
function theFunction(video_id,user_id){
    var user_id1=$('#video_lesson_'+video_id).val();
    $.ajax({
                url:'video_selection.php',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                 data: {'user_id1':user_id1,'video_id':video_id},
                success: function (data) {
                    var text="";
                    for (var i =0; i <= data.length; i++) {
                        var source="uploads/"+data[i];
                        var source1="uploads/"+data[i+1];
                       $("a[href='source']").attr('href', 'source1');

                    }


                }
            });
}
```

This is my Html code

```
 <a  video_id="<?php echo $f['id']; ?>" user_id="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"   onclick="theFunction(this.getAttribute('video_id','user_id'))"  href="uploads/<?php echo $f['file_path'];?>" class="popup-youtube start-btn "><span>Start</span></a>
```

Comment: <a  video_id="<?php echo $f['id']; ?>" user_id="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"   onclick="theFunction(this.getAttribute('video_id','user_id'))"  href="uploads/<?php echo $f['file_path'];?>" class="popup-youtube start-btn "><span>Start</span></a>

Comment: Are you using the youtube videos?

Comment: videos are store in upload folder

Comment: ` $("a[href='source']").attr('href', 'source1');` are you referring variables here? `source` and `source1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample code as below, it may help you:

```
<video width="256" height="192"  id="myVideo" controls autoplay>
    <source src="" id="mp4Source" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    var videoCount = 0;
    var player = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');
    var arr_video = new Array();

    $.ajax({
        url:'video_selection.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {'user_id1':user_id1,'video_id':video_id},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != 'undefined') {
                arr_video = data;
                videoCount = arr_video.length;              
                videoPlay(0);
                player.addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
            }
        }
    });

     // Set video source and start autoplay     
    function videoPlay(num) {
        $(mp4Vid).attr('src', "/uploads/" + arr_video[num]);
        player.load();
        player.play();
   }

   // Continuously play videos one after another
   function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if(i == (videoCount - 1)){
        i = 0;
        videoPlay(i);
    }
    else{
        videoPlay(i);
    }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `source` and `source1` as variables but you are using inside single quotes so these are considered as a string.

Replace this line

```
$("a[href='source']").attr('href', 'source1');
```

to this

```
$("a[href='"+source+"']").attr('href', source1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Suppose you have videos name list like this:

<ul id="videoList">

  <li vidUserId="<?=$f['id']?>-<?=$rows['id']?>" class="currentVideo">Video1</li>

  <li  vidUserId="<?=$f['id']?>-<?=$rows['id']?>">Video2</li>

  <li vidUserId="<?=$f['id']?>-<?=$rows['id']?>">Video3</li>

  <li  vidUserId="<?=$f['id']?>-<?=$rows['id']?>">Video4</li>

  <li  vidUserId="<?=$f['id']?>-<?=$rows['id']?>">Video5</li>

</ul>

vidUserId attr has video id and user id separated with the hyphen and adds a "currentVideo" class on currently running video, then on the end of this video get the next video id and user id and fire the  theFunction() like the below

   <script type="text/javascript">
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    video.onended = function(e) {

        var currentVideo = $('#videoList li.currentVideo');

        var nextVideo = $('#videoList li.currentVideo').next();

        if(nextVideo.length){

            nextVideo.addClass('currentVideo');

        }else{

            nextVideo = $('#videoList li').first();

            nextVideo.addClass('currentVideo');

        }


        var videoUserId = nextVideo.attr('vidUserId');

        var arrIds = videoUserId.split('-');

        var videoId = arrIds[0];

        var userId = arrIds[1];

        currentVideo.removeClass('currentVideo');

        theFunction(videoId,userId);

    };
</script>
```